# How can I connect an ESP32 to an A6 GSM module?

Tags: arduino, gsm, esp32

I'm really in need of help with this problem and as most commonly advised, I have researched and researched and researched for days and I can't figure out what's wrong...

With that being said, I'm working on a project that uses an ESP-32S ([pinout](https://cdn.instructables.com/FOL/YWLI/JEOILQ5U/FOLYWLIJEOILQ5U.LARGE.jpg?auto=webp&frame=1&width=1024&fit=bounds)) and an A6 GSM module. ([pinout](https://lastminuteengineers.com/wp-content/uploads/arduino/A6-GSM-GPRS-Module-Pinout.png)) I'm attempting to get them connected to have the A6 send data to ThingSpeak... My problem is that I can't get it to work... I have the exact same configuration between the two using an ESP8266 and it connects and works but with the ESP32S it just doesn't seem to work...

Below is the code I have used to connect the 32 to the A6 and everything says success and pass but it won't change any ThingSpeak values using any methods...

```
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_A6

#include "TinyGsmClient.h"
#include "ThingSpeak.h"


#define SerialMon Serial

HardwareSerial SerialAT(1);

bool modemConeted;

// Your GPRS credentials
// Leave empty, if missing user or pass
const char apn[]  = "wireless.twilio.com";
const char user[] = "";
const char pass[] = "";

bool dataSent = false;

TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);

TinyGsmClient client(modem);

void setup(){
  SerialMon.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  gsmModSetup();
}

void gsmModSetup() {

  // Set GSM module baud rate
  SerialAT.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 27, 26, false); //27 and 26 are the pins on the ESP32S connected to the U_Rxd/U_Txd pins of A6
  delay(3000);

  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.init();
  delay(3000);

  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  SerialMon.print("Modem: ");

  SerialMon.println(modemInfo);


  SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork()) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" OK");
  SerialMon.print("Connecting to ");
  SerialMon.print(apn);

  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, user, pass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(5000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" OK");
}

void loop(){

}
```

I'm using a Twilo Sim card that's loaded with data (as said above it works with esp8266 so not the SIM and not the board) The only part of this code that doesn't pass is the part that says GPRS connect. it never says pass or fail. It just sits for like five minutes then continues.

After this, I try and post to ThingSpeak and it gives ThingSpeak  ERROR-307 which means failed to connect to ThingSpeak... 
I have tried 2 different ways

The what I find the easy and normal way

```
ThingSpeak.setField(1, temp);
ThingSpeak.setField(2, h);
ThingSpeak.setField(3, p);
ThingSpeak.setField(4, pt);
ThingSpeak.writeFields(myChannelNumber, myWriteAPIKey);
```

and the more complicated way of connecting to the server then sends a GET command with all the values put together with strings.

```
if (client.connect(thingSpeakAddress, 80))
  {
    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: " + WriteAPIKey + "\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(thingSpeakData.length());
    client.print("\n\n");

    client.print(thingSpeakData);

  }
client.stop();
```

Yet neither work and I don't know what to do... My A6 is connected to the 32 using GPIO26 & 27 they're connected to the A6 U_Rxd/U_Txd pins. All boards share common ground as they should.

Any more guides to read or code to change or libraries to try would be extremely helpful as my days of digging has yielded nothing but frustration as one attempt after another fails. the readers of this really are my last hope in solving this problem that's hindering my farther progression.

(Any questions about anything on my end, please ask. -Thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enclose documentation shows ESP32S pins for HW Serial 0 RX/TX on pin GIPO01/GIPO03, HW Serial 1 RX/TX on pin GIPO09/GIPO10 Given you have attached no oter HW at the moment, why not try with the basic config with serial1
Read about this: https://github.com/G6EJD/ESP32-Using-Hardware-Serial-Ports and use the latest core ESP32 package (as of today 23.3.2020 is 1.04, previous releases had issues with serial. Do notforget to setup the serial a given in the article its different to esp8266 (!) so much about code compability. If you use the code on both platforms, you have to work with

```
#ifdef ESP32
          //configure serial for esp32
#elif ESP8266
        //configure serial for esp8266
#else
#error "Hardware not supported"
#endif
```

Here a small test routine for just the serial communication. If you type something in the input line of serial monitor it should be mirrored in the output window

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // set the data rate for the HardwareSerial port
  Serial2.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial2.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial2.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

You can then expand the serial2 to your settings. If it fails it may be dueto: U1UXD is unused and can be used for your projects. Some boards use this port for SPI Flash access though - so try Serial3.

Comment: I changed my pins to GPIO17/16 so I can use RX2 TX2 and now when it goes to post to the web it crashes and gives "Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled."

Comment: Try to use the "original" pins and use HWSer2 my guess is Serial1 is taken by Flash communication. ESP Exeption decoder would be a help here. After install you can paste the backtrace in and you would see the exact point of failure. ESP32 is a different "beast" than esp8266 due to closed source  only API) from Expressif. I had to rewrite some 1000 lines to get a trusted esp8266 app to run smootly on ESP32.